# Blender 2.9+ inwards pointing UV Map texture from mirrored object

Tags: uv, normals, mirror, mirror-modifier

quite the n00b concerning Blender and I ran into my first issue concerning the texture of a UV Map pointing in the wrong direction of a mirrored object.

To give context I attached a screenshot: Green marked side "normal" shows the texture how it should be. Red marked side "darkened" shows stair rows darkened (pointing inside). When I view the object from the back the correct texture (which would be the green one) is visible.

[image]

Methods I tried to create the mirrored object, knowing this could cause issues:

Method 1.1: Mirror object by short cut
Method 1.2: Mirror object using the Mirror modifier, then apply it and make a selection with key "p" from the mirrored part

Resulted in the same behavior (UV Map texture pointing in the wrong direction)

Attempts to fix it:

2. Apply scale after mirroring the object
3. Checking if the normals are correct:
   Method 2.1 Recalculating the normals
   Method 2.2 See if any normals are flipped (they are fine)
4. Trying to mirror the UV map (UV -> mirror) with "X Axis" and "Y Axis"

I tried to find a solution here and elsewhere and couldn't find anything related to this issue. If the information I provided isn't enough, please let me know what else I can provide.

Disclaimer: Unfortunately a moderator deleted my post, as a response to the possible solution provided by Crantisz. I don't have enough reputation to comment on his post so I had to go through this route: I have tried pressing shift + n, after applying scale, to recalculate the normals numerous times. Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue.

Also: I tried the solutions suggested in this post with no success:

[How to flip normals that won't flip](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168464/how-to-flip-normals-that-wont-flip)

Answer (score 0):

After applying scale, normals should be reverted. So go to edit mode, select all faces and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>