# Confused about missing faces on exported object

Tags: export, faces

In Blender, I have tried to create a coffee table that has 3 materials: Oak Shader for the table top. grey paint for the body and brushed metal for the handles. This is to be used as an imported furniture object into SweetHome3D.

It looks ok in Blender but when I export this as an object (dae or obj file), the object created appears to be missing faces on the table top, when imported to SweetHome3d. I have tried recreating the table top several times using extrude but the result is always the same. It does look ok in file explorer preview. I realise this seems to be a crossover issue with SweetHome3d but it must be something unusual about the model created by Blender and the initial Blender object I have created. Any ideas?

[image: file explorer 3d view]

[image: blender view]

[image: object n SweetHome3d]

[Here is the Blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/t/VcblrXrmAx2NlSeA)

Comment: Many faces are inverted, select all in Edit mode and recalculate the normals (Shift N)

Comment: @moonboots it's not enough to `Shift+N` because of [this bug](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/70977)

Comment: @Harry McKenzie Oh OK I was not aware of this bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @[moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots) has said, many faces are inverted. You can see it because they are red but they should be blue. Enable *Face Orientation* under *Overlays* to see this. You also have [this bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282322/is-having-2-or-more-faces-with-all-shared-vertices-a-bug-or-valid-geometry) in your mesh which cannot be solved [without technical understanding of the bug](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/70977) where 2 faces (potentially more) share the same set of vertices.

[image]

To workaround this bug and solve this, first go to your [`Python Console`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) and execute the following command. Note you have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice:

```
for m in D.meshes: m.validate()
```

Then you can <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to *Recalculate Outside* the Normals of the mesh (*Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for that. Unfortunately, the Python Console command has been stuck at the "..." stage since I ran it 30 minutes ago. Not getting True or False. Not sure why as I can see it worked for you and I played safe by using the file I shared with you.

Comment: you have to press `Enter` twice. First enter will yield "..." then second Enter will give True.

Comment: Thanks. That worked.